# В telegram не передается значение

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

В первый раз пишу телеграм бота. У него есть некоторые команды. Допустим:

/команда1,
/команда2,
текст, если введенной команды нет  списке

Для них сделан обработчик (взаимодействие с помощью вебхука).

Команда1 работает правильно.

А по команде2 обработчик должен выбрать из текстового файла рандомную строку и отдать её. Делаю с помощью такого кода:

```
$a =  file('./file.txt');
$preload_text = $a[array_rand($a)];

sendMessage($chat_id, $preload_text);
```

Но в телеграм не возвращает ничего, при вводе команды2.

Сделал новый файл `test.php` в той же директории, что и обработчик и пихнул в него код:

```
$a =  file('./file.txt');
echo $a[array_rand($a)];
```

Открываю site.ru/test.php в браузере - все отрабатывает правильно.

Если в `$preload_text` задаю просто строку то в телеграм её возвращает правильно

В чем тут проблема?

Comment: а *$preload_text* это точно строка, не массив строк?

Comment: @Anatol да, точно

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Ошибки отлавливаете?

Comment: @Anatol Я пока плохо представляю как отлаживать бота. Потому не отлавливаю

Comment: Бот к проблеме имеет вполне косвенное отношение. Запихайте этот код в `try-catch` и посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

```
$preload_text = $a[array_rand($a)];
```

возвращается string, как и должен => проблема в файле, возможно слишком много текста?